# Attempted to create a basic wordle clone and am running into roadblocks

Tags: arrays, c, function, cs50

New to coding, just a few weeks in now. Trying my hand at making a Wordle clone sounded like good practice, so I started earlier today. I have also really not learned a thing about pointers, by the way.

Running into problems on line 42:

```
string result = check(guess[i], key)
```

where I try to use my `check` function, the CLI returns this to me:

> incompatible pointer types initializing 'string' (aka 'char *') with an expression of type 'string *' (aka 'char **')

Problem two is I can get the checks for each letter of the guess, but they are stored in an array called `letter`, and I'd like to combine them in a string to say: 1st letter: right spot, 2nd letter: not in word... etc. Not sure if this is possible.

Also trying to pass the letter array back from my function and not sure how that works. But I can figure that one out, I think. I also considered passing back an `int` and from that I could extrapolate the results, but not to sure what way is best.

Sorry for the word vomit, but I do want to accomplish this and don't know where to go.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

string word_list[] = { "blind", "sheet", "crush", "relax", "drain",
    "label", "expel", "thump", "shade", "resin", "alert", "dream",
    "flood", "guard", "adult", "force", "wound", "drain", "cable"
};
string key;

string *check(string guess, string key);

int main(void)
{
    char ready;
    do {
        ready = get_char("Welcome to wordle! Are you ready to play? (y/n) ");
    } while (ready != 110 && ready != 121);

    if (ready == 121) {
        int ran;
        srand(time(NULL));
        ran = rand() % 18;
        key = word_list[ran];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    int guess_num = 1;
    string guess[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        do {
            guess[i] = get_string("Guess %i:\n", guess_num);
            string result = check(guess[i], key);
            printf("%s\n", result);

            if (strlen(guess[i]) == 5) {
                guess_num++;
            }
        } while (strlen(guess[i]) != 5);
}

string *check(string guess, string keys)
{
    string correct = "in correct spot." ;
    string almost = "in the word, wrong spot.";
    string not = "not in word.";
    string letter[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (guess[i] == key[])
        {
            letter[i] = correct;
        }
        else if (guess[i] == key[0] || guess[i] == key[1] || guess[i] == key[2] || guess[i] == key[3] || guess[i] == key[4])
        {
            letter[i] = almost;
        }
        else
        {
            letter[i] = not;
        }
    return letter;
}
```

I have tried multiple sites and tutorials but no really understanding, or solutions are for a similar problem but dont address my own.

Comment: Please point out which line is #42.

Comment: `if (guess[i] == key[])` <- what is the intention here?

Comment: line 42 is the string result = check(guess[i], key).  and if (guess[i] == key[i]); was what i meant, checking if the letter of the guess corresponded with the word-key

Comment: `string` is an array of `guess`, but `check()` returns a `string*`, i.e. a pointer to `string` - the two are not assignment compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- the test `if (guess[i] == key[])` is a syntax error. You should write:

  ```
    if (guess[i] == key[i])
  ```
- the function `check` returns a local array: this is invalid. The array becomes invalid as soon as the function returns so a pointer to its first element must not be returned to the caller.  You should instead take the array as an argument (defined in the calling function) and update it in `check()`.  note also that `letter` should be a `char` array of length 6, not a `string` (which is just a `char *`).
- you should use character constants instead of cryptic ASCII codes `ready != 110 && ready != 121`:

  ```
   ready != 'n' && ready != 'y'
  ```
- there are actually 19 words in the `word_list` array, do not use `18` but an expression that evaluates to the length of the array.

Here is modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

string word_list[] = {
    "blind", "sheet", "crush", "relax", "drain",
    "label", "expel", "thump", "shade", "resin",
    "alert", "dream", "flood", "guard", "adult",
    "force", "wound", "drain", "cable"
};
string key;

void check(string guess, string key, char letter[]);

int main(void)
{
    char ready;
    do {
        ready = get_char("Welcome to wordle! Are you ready to play? (y/n) ");
    } while (ready != 'n' && ready != 'y');

    if (ready == 'y') {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int ran = rand() % (sizeof word_list / sizeof word_list[0]);
        key = word_list[ran];
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

    int guess_num = 1;
    string guess[5];
    char result[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        do {
            guess[i] = get_string("Guess %i:\n", guess_num);
        } while (strlen(guess[i]) != 5);

        check(guess[i], key, result);
        printf("%s\n", result);
        guess_num++;
        if (!strcmp(guess[i], key)) {
            printf("found!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("not found! word was %s\n", key);
}

void check(string guess, string keys, char letter[6])
{
    char correct = 'O';
    char almost = 'X';
    char not = '.';

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (guess[i] == key[i]) {
            letter[i] = correct;
        } else
        if (guess[i] == key[0] || guess[i] == key[1] || guess[i] == key[2]
        ||  guess[i] == key[3] || guess[i] == key[4]) {
            letter[i] = almost;
        } else {
            letter[i] = not;
        }
    }
    letter[5] = '\0';  // set the null terminator
}
```

Comment: first off nice name, second i have one question to wrap this up, when you declare the check function it has no return value, eg the int before int main(void). how are you able to access the letters variable from a different function. Sorry if this is very basic, i just assumed that to access anything from a separate function you had to return it. Thanks

Comment: @CharlieWebster: `check` takes a `char letter[]` argument, which is received as a pointer to the array of `char` defined in the calling function. The function constructs a string into this array with Os and Xs for the *correct* and *almost* matches. There is no need to *pass it back to the caller*, the caller's array is updated via the pointer.

Comment: @chqrlie Nor am I familiar (with _Wordle_). Just presuming 'scoring' is similar to _Mastermind_ that scores doesn't give _double credit_ for elements of the guess... Cheers! `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3: actually [Wordle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordle) works this way: duplicate misplaced letters are highlighted even if they match the same letter in the secret word. The behavior is different from the much older [Mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)) board game where only the count of matching and misplaced pegs is provided.

Comment: @chqrlie Just finished the Wikipedia article you linked-to, and now know TOO MUCH about a game I've never played! Life, eh? `:-)`